# artifactory - get dependency info

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

We build our gradle using a jenkins pipeline. After compiling we upload to the artifactory repo. The problem is that we cannot see in the build info dependencies that were pulled from the artifactory during the build. Dependencies are defined in the gradle file and not in the pipeline so seems that upon uploading, we do not provide this data to the artifactory.
Can we set so all downloaded packages from the artifactory during the build will appear in the build info?
Our pipeline looks like:

```
                    def uploadSpec = """{
                        \"files\": [
                        ALL_FILES
                        ]
                    }"""
                    def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'https://artifactory.com/artifactory', credentialsId: params.ARTIFACTORY_USER
                    server.bypassProxy = true
                    server.upload(uploadSpec)

                    def buildInfo = server.upload uploadSpec

                    buildInfo.env.capture = true
                    buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10
                    server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

No 'downloadSpec' since all dowloading packages are managed in a gradle file

Comment: Yes, You can. Here is the example which does exactly what you are looking for. https://github.com/jfrogtraining/kubernetes_example/blob/master/gradle-example/Jenkinsfile

Comment: thanks, i figured it out and successfully run it. Seems there is NO way to integrate a FileSpec within the build. So I used a 'rtGradle' and its arguments.